# UI Design (How to make it look professional)

Tags: html, css, website-deployment

I recently finished (well almost) developing my first Frontend and Backend web development project and hosted it online. I noticed a few errors pop up but I can fix those in due time. The main problem that I am facing is the ui design. How do I make a site look more professional? Are there any tips and tricks that professional web developers use? I don't want to use ready made templates. And copying someone's web template is good for practice but not for developing a project. Any tips?

Comment: This is a massive topic which some people build their entire careers around. You are probably best to get a book on interface design or do some browser searching for websites that go into it in detail. The question is really to broad for you to get a reasonable answer here.

Comment: Yes, I realized later on that that might be the case after all. I am planning on first designing how the website should look first and then implementing it instead of just going about it while coding. Anyways, thanks. I'll see if I can find a website that can help me out or something.